# Angular cli installation

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

while installing the angular cli, got this warning:

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4
>   (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4:
>   wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) but on checking the version of Angular it
>   shows:  Angular CLI: 6.0.7 Node: 8.11.2 OS: win32 x64.

now when am trying to create a directory at the command prompt its not creating any directory.
When running this command `ng new conFusion -dir=./conFusion --style=scss`
it is not creating any directory. please lemme know the reason

Comment: how is this java related? did you check the official angular pages? if you follow what they do there, you really can't go wrong.

Comment: when trying to give ng serve command it says angular.json file not found

Comment: See this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5431 and try      `ng new conFusion --directory conFusion --style=scss`

Comment: Thanks Vikas. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything about it. It is just a (useless) warning which annoys many people.

See https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20639